# Adding a script in Excel but showing Local format displaying incorrectly

Tags: javascript, excel, power-automate

Using Power automate to run a script which works fine but I need to run it in UTC time and date format (Singapore)

using a script I found here

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  let worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1");

  // Get the cells at A1 and B1.
  let dateRange = worksheet.getRange("P17");
  let timeRange = worksheet.getRange("Q17");

  let date = new Date(Date.now() + (3600 * 1000 * 0));

  dateRange.setValue(date.toLocaleDateString());

  timeRange.setValue(date.toLocaleTimeString());
```

}

I need to change it away from local time as that is in American format plus 3 hours Perth Vs Sydney

thank you

Comment: If you're doing it from PowerAutomate then why not pass the date from there as a parameter?  It's easy to do in the flow itself.

Comment: Hi thanks are you saying pass the date to the excel document ? How would, that be done?

Comment: A couple of documents to read up on ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/tutorials/excel-power-automate-returns ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/develop/power-automate-integration

Comment: Hi thanks - I miss read your reply I have a power automate script to automatically setup to run the script. the script is running the above but pulling in where the Power Automate server is located hence the timeRange.setValue(date.toLocaleTimeString()); - all I need to do is put in into UTC time ?

Thank you